# iOS how do I detect when a IUButton with showMenuAsPrimaryAction is beginning to present the menu?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uimenu

I have a UIButton with the menu set to a UIMenu (with chidren) and ShowMenuAsPrimaryAction set to true.

but I would like to know when the button is pressed and the menu is about to be presented so I can stop other UITextFields from being FirstResponder?

Regards Christian Arild Stœr Andersen

Answer (score 0):

I think you can definitely determine it with `contextMenuInteraction`:

```swift
class MenuButton: UIButton {

    var onDismissMenu: (() -> Void)?
    var onShowMenu: (() -> Void)?

    override func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, willEndFor configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration, animator: UIContextMenuInteractionAnimating?) {
        super.contextMenuInteraction(interaction, willEndFor: configuration, animator: animator)

        onDismissMenu?()
    }

    override func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, willDisplayMenuFor configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration, animator: UIContextMenuInteractionAnimating?) {
        super.contextMenuInteraction(interaction, willDisplayMenuFor: configuration, animator: animator)

        onShowMenu?()
    }
}
```

Then handle `onShowMenu` to hide the keyboard, something like:

```swift
button.onShowMenu = { [weak self] in
    self?.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks That looks like it would work I was thinking of trying to subclass UIButton and see what I could override in there so this looks like a brilliant solution

Comment: You can use `UIContextMenuInteraction` also, and handle actions on `UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate` of which view was adapted with. However, I think this is easier. Could you please mark this as the correct answer if you found it to be helpful? That would be fantastic.